# Citations with biblatex and natbib compatibility mode

Tags: biblatex

I recently changed from BibTeX to `biblatex` and now struggle to have my citations in my text as I want them to and the same in my bibliography.

I'd like to have it for 2 authors like that:

> *Familyname, Initial of the first name und Familyname, Initial of the first name,....*

for 3 authors like that:

> *Familyname, Initial of the first name; Familyname, Initial of the first name  und Familyname, Initial of the first name,....*

and for more than 3 like that:

> *Familyname, Initial of the first name et. al.*

besides that I think I maybe need to change something that the citation commands (`\cite`) are doing still the same as they did before with BibTeX and `natbib`. There are no brackets when I compile around the year, which where there before. Meaning for `\cite` instead of *Author (year)*  I now get *Author, year*

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, 
natbib=true, 
backend=biber, 
giveninits=true, 
uniquename=init,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
maxbibnames=3, 
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{pagetotal}
}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}% Kursiv für alle Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}% aufrechte/normale Schrift für         Zeitschriftennamen


\addbibresource{Literatur - Kopie.bib}
\usepackage[flushmargin, hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage[a4paper,
left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,
top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

Dieses Skalenniveau ist insofern sinnvoll, da \glqq Aussagen über Differenzen möglich sind\grqq \ \citep[S.29]{Langer1977} und diese auch genau angegeben werden können  \citep[vgl.][]{Hartung1999}.
...
Die interessierenden Objekte werden in dieser Arbeit wie bei Johann \cite{Bacher2010} \glqq Klassifikationsobjekte\grqq \ (S.15) genannt oder wie bei den meisten Autoren einfach als zu klassifizierende Objekte, zu untersuchende Objekte, Objekte oder Klassifikationsdaten bezeichnet \citep{Eckes1980, Hartung1999, Hoberg2003, Handl2017}. 

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\printbibliography
```

Comment: Is that you: https://golatex.de/literaturverzeichnis-t21118.html? Technically speaking you are not using `natbib`, you are just using `biblatex`'s `natbib` compatibility mode. I'll edit your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: BTW: Don't use `\glqq Aussagen über Differenzen möglich sind\grqq` write `\enquote{Aussagen über Differenzen möglich sind}`. Or even `\textcquote[29]{Langner1977}{Aussagen über Differenzen möglich sind}`. With `biblatex` you should also never have to write "S." in the postnote of your `\cite` commands, it will be added automatically: `\cite[380]{sigfridsson}`

Comment: Yes, you changes as recommended, but you did not clean up your preamble as recommended (you really should, I bet you don't even use all the packages you load). Plus I would have thought it to be polite if you had replied in the German forum as well and would not have run away to a different site...

Comment: Don't panic! It's just a stupid bibliography. It'll be fine. I know that the tone in German forums can seem a bit harsh at times (I rarely have that feeling in English speaking sites, I don't know why that is - maybe I'm more sensitive when I communicate in my native language ...) but people usually mean well and just try to bring their point across, some have learned that it is more useful to be terse and omit niceties in such a forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the desired format with semicolon (ugh) by redefining `multinamedelim` accordingly, it seems that you do not want to redefine `finalnamedelim`. "et al." instead of "u.a." is obtained by redefining the `andothers` bibliography string. The brackets in `\cite` can be obtained by using the right command for the job, see below.

Note also how I used `csquotes`' `\enquote` and `\textcquote` instead of `\glqq` and `\grqq`. `\enquote` can be used to put quotation marks around a passage of text, `\textcquote` can be used to wrap a passage in quotation marks and add a citation all in one command.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authoryear, 
  natbib=true, 
  backend=biber, 
  giveninits=true, 
  uniquename=init,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  eprint=false,
  maxbibnames=3, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  autocite=inline,
]{biblatex}

\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearfield{pagetotal}
}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}% Kursiv für alle Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}% aufrechte/normale Schrift für Zeitschriftennamen

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et\addnbthinspace al\adddot},% oder \addnbthinspace statt \addabbrsvpace
}

\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\parencite{sigfridsson} -- \citep{sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson} -- \citet{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}

Dieses Skalenniveau ist insofern sinnvoll, da \textcquote[29]{worman}{Aussagen über Differenzen möglich sind} und diese auch genau angegeben werden können \parencite[vgl.][]{sigfridsson}.
...

Ein weiteres \enquote{Zitat} aber diesmal ohne direkte Quellenangabe  \autocite[vgl.][]{pines}.

Die interessierenden Objekte werden in dieser Arbeit wie bei \citeauthor{worman} \textcquote[15]{worman}{Klassifikationsobjekte} genannt.


\cite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,companion,pines,aksin,cotton}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of all sorts of citations and bibliographies in the MWE. There is too much going on to list it all in a useful manner, sorry...]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer!! This is really helping! One more little question: How do I change the comma between only two authors into the "und" as in the example references with Sigfridsson und Ryde?

Comment: @Lisa You have to remove the line ` \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} ` from your code. You should have `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}` instead. (As in this example.)

Comment: Ah I think I kind of overlooked this one before. It worked now!! Thank you so much for your time and your help!! This was perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Don't be discouraged when people make you aware of a possibly incomplete minimal working example. They just want to solve the problem more effectively. :)

I am not an expert at all, because of which I might understand your trouble even better. So I tried to compress your code a little. Overall, your code ends up doing already most of the things you wanted it to. Here, I exemplary use the .bib-entries you provided over at [golatex.de](https://golatex.de/literaturverzeichnis-t21118.html)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}    
\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}    
@InCollection{Wilks2011, 
    author    = {Daniel S. Wilks}, 
    title     = {{C}luster {A}nalysis}, 
    booktitle = {Statistical Methods in the Atmospheric Sciences}, 
    publisher = {Academic Press}, 
    year      = {2011}, 
    volume    = {100}, 
    series    = {International Geophysics}, 
    chapter   = {15}, 
    pages     = {603--616}, 
    edition   = {3.}, 
    isbn      = {9780123850232}, 
    doi       = {https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-385022-5.00015-4}, 
    issn      = {0074-6142}, 
    keywords  = {hierarchical clustering, dendrogram, Ward's method, K-means}, 
    url       = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123850225000154}, } 

@Book{Handl2017, 
    title     = {{M}ultivariate {A}nalysemethoden: {T}heorie und {P}raxis mit {R}}, 
    publisher = {Springer Spektrum}, 
    year      = {2017}, 
    author    = {Andreas Handl and Torben Kuhlenkasper}, 
    volume    = {3., wesentlich überarbeitete Auflage}, 
    address   = {Berlin \& Heidelberg}, 
    isbn      = {978-3-662-54754-0}, 
    date      = {2017-08-03}, 
    ean       = {9783662547540},  } 

@Misc{EuropeanCommision2016, 
    author       = {{European Commision}}, 
    title        = {From 6 to 28 members}, 
    howpublished = {Webseite der Europäischen Kommision}, 
    month        = jun, 
    year         = {2016},
    url          = {https://ec.europa.eu/neighbourhood-enlargement/policy/from-6-to-28-members_en}, } 

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}    
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sortlocale=de_DE,
natbib = true, giveninits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} \begin{document}

First citation \citet{Wilks2011}.\\
Second citation \citet{Handl2017}.\\ 
Third citation \citet{EuropeanCommision2016}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

Note that for the brackets to appear correctly you can use the natbib-equivalent commands `\citet`, `\citep` snd so on. Then, this already looks very much like you want it to look. :)
After that, look at @moewe 's answer, he provided you with the necessary "Latex-Hacking" for the details, like the semicolons as author separations, or, e.g. the code

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
   andothers = {et\addnbthinspace al\adddot},% oder \addnbthinspace statt \addabbrsvpace
}
```

to change the "u.a." to "et al.".

Best of luck with your thesis! :)

Comment: Thank you!! Do you know how to have the und between two authors in JabRef asit is inyour example with the two authors?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is done by default. One could change it by redefining `finalnamedelim` as pointed out by moewe (which you *should* not do if you want the "und"). Is it not placing "und" between only two authors when you compile my or moewe's code? Maybe I misread your question; I did never work with JabRef, but your problem does lie in Latex, doesn't it? Perhaps clarify what you mean.

Comment: I do not write my References in Latex directly as I use JabRef for them. I used moewe´s way to change the "u.a." for many authors which worked completely fine. But if i only have two authors I always get: _Handl, Kuhlenkasper, 2017_ for example and I would like to change the comma between the two authors into an "und" . So I hoped there is a way to program that somehow

Comment: But JabRef only creates your "Literaturdatei", right? So JabRef has nothing to do with the actual look of the citation. That is all Latex. If you now don't get the same behaviour as me with my example above, you did something different in your code. Do you use the exact same code as I posted above and still get a different result? Because otherwise, I need to know which code you use to be able to find a mistake. If you want, we can discuss this over at golatex.de, and talk about your problem via skype or so. I have time on my hand at the moment. :)

Comment: I think you are right with the file thing. But I am pretty sure I have the same codeas you had in your example and it is still not working.... how should I send you my code, that you could have a look at it?

Comment: I am on goLatex now ;)